# How to prove that there are at least two different unital homomorphisms for field $K\rightarrow K$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

How to prove that exists a field K such that there are two unital homomorphisms between fields $f:K\rightarrow K$? Homomorphism is unital if $f(1) = 1$

Comment: This is not generally true. Take K=Z_2 for instance, then there is just one homomorphism.

Comment: More generally, take $K$ to be any prime field (e.g. $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$). Less trivially, take $K = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've edit edited the question. To prove is that exists a field $K$ s.t. there are two unital homomorphisms in it.

Comment: What examples of fields do you know? You probably know one that has 2 such homomorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$K=\Bbb C$, take identity and complex conjugation.